# What is valid "related tasks names" or "related task names" as name of list?

Tags: word-choice

I want to name list.
List contains related tasks names.

What is valid (I assume that both is good and first is more natural).

1. related task names
2. related tasks names

My language is little different so for me it is not natural but I want speak it in English.

Comment: "task" is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural)